# Create thumbnail from image and insert in SQLite as blob

Tags: python, sqlite, blob

I'd like to create a thumbnail from an image and then insert that thumbnail in SQLite as BLOB. (without saving thumbnail as file first)

My code;

```
from PIL import Image

size = 120,120
file = "a.jpg"

imgobj = Image.open(file)          
imgobj.thumbnail(size)
```

But how to save it to SQLite as BLOB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are  many ways, and this is one of them:

```
import sqlite3
from PIL import Image

size = 120, 120
file = "/tmp/a.jpg"
imgobj = Image.open(file)
imgobj.thumbnail(size)

con = sqlite3.connect("/tmp/imagesdb")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table img (x blob)")
cur.execute("insert into img(x) values(?)", [ buffer(imgobj.tostring()) ] )
con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()

# read it back.
con = sqlite3.connect("/tmp/imagesdb")
cur = con.cursor()
row = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM img')
for item in row:
    print item #dont worry just pointers to files...
    #print item[0] # has actually binary contents.
```

Comment: [ buffer(imgobj.tostring()) ] did the trick. Thanks a million !!

Comment: It's almost done buth there's a strange error. I've changed this: cur.execute("create table img (f text, x blob)")
cur.execute("insert into img(f,x) values(?,?)", file, [ buffer(imgobj.tostring()) ] ) but i receive an error:     cur.execute("insert into img(f,x) values(?,?)", file, [ buffer(imgobj.tostring()) ] )
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: when changing it this way: cur.execute("create table img (f text, x blob)")
cur.execute("insert into img(f,x) values(?,?)", (file, [ buffer(imgobj.tostring()) ]) ) the error is:     cur.execute("insert into img(f,x) values(?,?)", (file, [ buffer(imgobj.tostring()) ]) )
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: FIXED: removed the Square brackets [ ] -> cur.execute("insert into img(f,x) values(?,?)", (file, buffer(imgobj.tostring()))