# PIL image to sqlite3 blob and reverse ?

Tags: python, sqlite, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library

I followed [instructions found on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350415/create-thumbnail-from-image-and-insert-in-sqlite-as-blob/36745785#36745785) to load images into sqlites i failed in exporting the data from sqlite3 to jpeg images.

can you help me to solve this ?

here is the way i prepare the image :

```
import io
import sqlite3
import picamera
from PIL import Image

# Create the in-memory stream
stream = io.BytesIO()
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.rotation = 180
    camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg')
# "Rewind" the stream to the beginning so we can read its content
stream.seek(0)
image = Image.open(stream)
```

I can save the PIL image to check it :

```
image.save("out.jpg", "JPEG", quality=100, optimize=True, progressive=True)
```

and then store the image as show in the above solution :

```
# storing images into sqlite3 database 
con = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table img (x blob)")
cur.execute("insert into img(x) values(?)", [ buffer( image.tostring() )] )
con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()
```

I can't find how looping over the table records and exporting the blob as single jpeg files.

Best regards

Comment: Why do you want to do all this hard work to come up with an inefficient system? It's so much easier and more performant to save images in the filesystem.

Comment: during data acquisition phase (image, gps, other sensors on a Raspberry PI) i thought it could be nicer to have all data together and then just download 1 database file for processing on an other computer.

Answer (score 4):

Save your image to a `BytesIO` object (similar to how you are capturing your image):

```
stream = io.BytesIO()
image.save(stream, format="JPEG")
```

Get the `bytes` object containing the encoded image:

```
imagebytes = stream.getvalue()
```

Then insert that `bytes` object as a query parameter into a query:

```
mydb.execute("INSERT INTO images VALUES (?, ?)", (imagename, imagebytes))
```

Comment: hi i think that part of he script is ok for me. i wonder how i can export images as jpeg files from blob stored in a sqlite db.